# How to find a usb driver for Yzi tablet?

Tags: android, driver

I recently acquired the tablet "Yzi" running Android 4.0.3. I want to use it on debug mode in Eclipse. After contacting the manufacturer's technical support (eviGroup), it replied that no usb driver had been developped for this tablet for use in debug mode, but the tablet was recognized only as mass storage device.
I would to know if there was any way to find a driver for the recognition of the tablet in debug mode.

Thank you.

Edit : I found a solution for Windows with [PdaNet for Android](http://www.junefabrics.com/android/download.php). Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to run linux on your development machine, you could work around the problem as per-device drivers are not required.

You would do the following:

1. enable usb debugging in the tablet's settings menu
2. plug in the device run lsusb and write down the VID of the tablet (unplug it and re-run if it's unclear which device is the tablet)
3. add a corresponding entry to your udev rules (see android docs), reload the udev rules, and re-plug the device
4. add an entry to your ~/.android/adb_usb.ini (note that here you use a 0x prefix), adb kill-server and then adb devices

From what I've heard the process is somewhat simpler on a Mac.  On Windows, you may be able to take a driver for some other android device and change it's VID/PID to match your tablet, though you may have to work around driver signing issues.

It is theoretically possible that your device might not support adb over USB.

Another option may be to run adb over wifi

You could also re-contact the vendor and specifically request an "ADB" driver - that may make more sense to the person you are talking to than "debug mode".  Or you could do a web search on the device name, or the device's VID and adb and see if someone else has a specific solution.